# How to make sense of the for loop in this decompiled code?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, elf

```
  int v0[6]; // [esp+1h] [ebp-37h] BYREF
  char v1[23]; // [esp+19h] [ebp-1Fh] BYREF

  qmemcpy(v0, "VMPZB^I[f)*+.){*~yyx", 20);
  v0[5] = 2133096749;
  strcpy(v1, "%-){$y-y+-.x)~y)*`");
  for ( *(_DWORD *)&v1[19] = 0; *(_DWORD *)&v1[19] <= 42u; ++*(_DWORD *)&v1[19] )
    *((_BYTE *)v0 + *(_DWORD *)&v1[19]) ^= 29u;
  puts(v0);
  exit(0);
}
```

My Understanding so far is this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
   int v0[6];
   char v1[23];
   memcpy(v0, "VMPZB^I[f)*+.){*~yyx", 20);
   v0[5] = 2133096749;
   strcpy(v1, "%-){$y-y+-.x)~y)*`");
   for (int i = 19; i <= 42; ++i) {
    *((unsigned char *)v0 + *(unsigned int *)&v1[i]) ^= 29;
}
   cout<<v0<<'\n'<<v1;
}
```

I am not able to make sense of the for loop, and it is most likely wrong. Could someone help me understand?

I have referred to stackoverflow for similar problems, maybe I do not have a proper understanding on pointers but the for loop has me stumped.

Comment: It looks like `v0` and `v1` should be combined as a single char array. You'll need to figure out the characters that `2133096749` would represent and put them in the right place. Then the loop iterates from 0 to 42 and xors each byte with 29.

Comment: The *(_DWORD *)&v1[19]* is your *i*, the loop starts with *i=0;*.

Comment: Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/drxfEd88b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop in the decompiled code is a bit tricky to understand because it involves pointer arithmetic and bitwise operations.

1. It initializes a pointer to the 20th element of the `v1` array. This is done by `*(_DWORD *)&v1[19] = 0;`. `_DWORD` is a data type representing a double word (32 bits), which is equivalent to unsigned int in C++. So, this line is equivalent to `unsigned int *ptr = (unsigned int *)&v1[19]; *ptr = 0;` in C++. It's creating a pointer to the 20th element of `v1` and setting the value at that location to 0.
2. The condition of the for loop checks if the value at the location pointed to by the pointer is less than or equal to 42. This is done by `*(_DWORD *)&v1[19] <= 42u;`.
3. In each iteration of the loop, it increments the value at the location pointed to by the pointer. This is done by `++*(_DWORD *)&v1[19];`.
4. Inside the loop, it performs a bitwise XOR operation on the elements of the `v0` array. The index of the element to be XORed is determined by the value at the location pointed to by the pointer. This is done by `*((_BYTE *)v0 + *(_DWORD *)&v1[19]) ^= 29u;`. `_BYTE` is a data type representing a byte (8 bits), which is equivalent to unsigned char in C++. So, this line is equivalent to `v0[*ptr] ^= 29;` in C++.

The equivalent C++ code for the for loop would be:

```cpp
unsigned int *ptr = (unsigned int *)&v1[19];
*ptr = 0;
for (; *ptr <= 42; ++(*ptr)) {
    v0[*ptr] ^= 29;
}
```

This code is likely to cause a segmentation fault because it accesses the `v0` array out of its bounds. The `v0` array has only 6 elements, but the loop tries to access up to the 42nd element. This is undefined behavior in C++. The decompiled code might not be correct or it might be intentionally obfuscated.